# Constructing Buttons with a Factory

Tags: angularjs

Essentially, different views in my app have different footer buttons, and some views don't have any buttons at all. This is currently how I have the button creation set up:

In each controller where there are buttons, I have the following in the init function:

```
var buttons = {"pageclass":"manageorders","buttons":[{"buttonText":"DELETE ORDER","iconclass":"delete","action":$scope.deleteChecked,"args":"","show":true,"disableButton":true,"overlayName":null},{"buttonText":"EMAIL ORDER","iconclass":"email","action":$scope.buttonClicked,"args":"'email'","show":true,"disableButton":true,"overlayName":"email"},{"buttonText":"PRINT ORDER","iconclass":"print","action":$scope.buttonClicked,"args":"'print'","show":true,"disableButton":true,"overlayName":"print"},{"buttonText":"CANCEL ORDERS","iconclass":"reject","action":$scope.approveOrders,"args":"null, 'Y'","show":true,"disableButton":true,"overlayName":null},{"buttonText":"APPROVE ORDERS","iconclass":"approve","action":$scope.approveOrders,"args":"null, 'Y'","show":true,"disableButton":true,"overlayName":null},{"buttonText":"CREATE NEW ORDER","iconclass":"new","action":$scope.newOrder,"args":'',"show":true,"disableButton":true,"overlayName":null}]};

$scope.$emit('assignButtons', buttons);
```

Then in my app's main controller:

```
$scope.$on('assignButtons', function(event, buttons) {
  $scope.buttonList = buttons;
});
```

Then I have an ng-repeat in my index view:

```
<div class="footerbuttons" ng-repeat="button in buttonList.buttons" ng-class="buttonList.pageclass" ng-cloak>
          <button 
              ng-click="button.action(button.args)" 
              ng-disabled="button.disableButton" 
              ng-if="button.show" 
              class="btn utility btn-small" 
              open-overlay named="button.overlayName">
              {{button.buttonText}} 
              <i ng-class="button.iconclass"></i>
          </button> 
</div>
```

When the route changes, I empty buttonList.

This all works fine, but to create the buttons in each controller like that is a little bit sloppy and I'd love to clean it up a bit and make it more reusable, but I have no idea where to even start. The main issue that I may run into is that each button has a specific function in its controller that I need to use (you can see in the current set up that I have that I am referring to the function as "action"'s value). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you tried using custom directives?

Comment: I could use a custom directive, but would I not still have to send the same button information from each controller? Or could a directive make this more efficient somehow?